1999 Toyata Camry AC works great half the time
Just recently my air conditioner decided it work when it want to. It will work when I first start the car for an indefinite amount of time blowing nice cold air, but then it will cut off showing a flashing air conditioning light at the button. I put more Freon with oil in it since it might have leaked over the last 25 years. More did go in it, but still acting the same. I have notice if I am in park or neutral I can cut it off and on and it works again temporarily. WTF? Is there a censor or port that needs cleaning. I'm on a budget and would like to figure it out before getting took for a ride in the pocket.

The only way to understand your problem requires connecting a set of refrigeration gauges to the low and high side to measure operating pressures at specific rpm. If you're unfamiliar with using manifold gauges, you're already in the deep end of the pool. Installing more refrigerant may exacerbate the problem if overfilling causes a pressure sensor to trigger and shut down compressor operation. This is just guessing without more information. Service manuals are needed to know operating pressures, diagnosing issues not mentioned like one or two cooling fans are worn out/dead, etc.
